# Increase versionCode by one Automatically after executing packageReleaseJar

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have following in android tag of build.gradle in order to increase versionCode:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
        List<String> runTasks = gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames();
        def value = 0
        for (String item : runTasks)
            if (item.contains("packageReleaseJar")) {
                value = 1;
            }

        def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + value
        versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = code.toString()
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 8
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode code
            versionName version
            testApplicationId 'se.android.instrumenttest'
            testInstrumentationRunner 'se.android.Runner'

            printf("\n--------" + "VERSION DATA--------"
                    + "\n" + "- CODE: " + versionCode + "\n" +
                    "- NAME: " + versionName + "\n----------------------------\n")
        }

    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }
```

The idea taken from [commonsguy sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/HelloVersioning).

I expect that when I execute `packageReleaseJar` task using Gradle wrapper, versionCode increased by one. But it is not working as expected.

I guess it could be related to `generateReleaseBuildConfig` task.

What could be the reason and what is solution for that?

**Addenda**

```
def getVersionCode() {
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
        def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()

    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }
    return code
}
```

This method is not working as expected, but when use the logic of method in the android tag, problem will be solved:

```
def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
        def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 8
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode code
            versionName version
            testApplicationId 'se.android.instrumenttest'
            testInstrumentationRunner 'se.android.Runner'

            printf("\n--------" + "VERSION DATA--------\n" +
                    "- CODE: " + versionCode + "\n" +
                    "- NAME: " + versionName +
                    "\n----------------------------\n")
        }

    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32509044/2016562

Comment: I just tried to use `def getMyNumber()` method, but as you know I can't use it inside android tag since inner methods are not supported, and when I use it outside android tag, it just doen't work as expected. I add my code to addenda in the question. Check out and let me know if you have time.